# How can I check that a PostGIS database (schema) is correctly backed up?

Tags: postgis

I'm something of a novice user of PostGIS. I have some valuable data in a single schema on a PostGIS database. I believe that I've saved a backup of the data etc to a local file using pgAdmin - but many of the options available when doing this are unfamiliar/confusing. I'd like to have some way to check that the data is correctly backed up (without risking the existing live data). Can this be done simply?

I have access to pgAdmin and QGIS.

....Additional....

I believe there to be longer term backups of the whole database (etc) as part of my company's ordinary IT processes - what I'm wanting to have to hand is a process where (as one of the supervising GIS staff) I can take steps to protect the data - this might be before making bigger changes to large amounts of data, or before bigger changes to table structure.

Comment: The database is PostgreSQL; PostGIS is a spatial column extension.  Database-centric questions are best asked in a database-centric SE, like [dba.se]

Comment: Thanks. Fair point.  I tend to ask here because (as a self-declared novice) I don't know whether  the spatial extension/dimension to the data makes a difference in most cases. I'm really an end-user not a database administrator (although obviously the dividing line is fuzzy). However in this case I can appreciate that this is indeed a basic PostgreSQL question. I'm assuming that pgAdmin handles the spatial data too...

Comment: sidenote: while a proper dump via the meant-for facilities in the PostgreSQL environment is arguably also the proper way here, especially if the DB design is complex enough (triggers, views, custom types, roles etc.), if it's only (!) the raw data you want to backup I guess there's no shame in saving it as CSVs to start with. `COPY`/`\COPY` is blazingly fast, and setting up PostGIS on a new server is trivial. version considerations are non-existent, CSVs are highly compressable and access/interchangeability is given almost universally (e.g. QGIS).

Answer (score 1):

When your database has blown up, you do not want a *backup*, but your original database *restored*.
So the only way to test your backup indeed is to restore it.

You could restore in a VM, or on another computer, or into a second Postgres installation (with a different port).

(In general, for testing things, it is useful to know how [to create](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) a second, throwaway Postgres installation.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference...I'd understood that you would save a backup to a file, then if necessary 'restore' from this backup file - and by doing so you'd be back where you started. Maybe I'm getting the language confused... I realise that restoring from this backup would test if it works, but I assume that this would consequently risk (overwrite) the live data.

Comment: I did not intend to contradict your question in any way.

Comment: No worries. Thanks. The think about being out of my depth is that I don't know what I do and don't know...